# how to fire dragble event in zk calendar component

Tags: java, zk

Hi zk provide Drop event, but we need drag event for Calendar.When user drag content in that time some available field will be display, after drop it will be remove.

Answer (score 1):

Zk doesn't provide a drag event at all.
So you have to use jquery to a add one to your component and fire
a zk event your self. Here is a short [jq guide for dragging](http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/). Number 6
looks like the stuff you want to do.

Now, you could send an [zk event](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing) in the callback method.
But, I think if you try to update the UI at server side, you
could get problems, because of zks repainting. I never 
done this my self, so you have to try. But for sure, you 
could mark the droppable areas at client side so you won't
have this problems.

If you try what I just discribed, please tell us your experiences
or problems, so that I/we can help.